# C# regex need characters after \player_n\

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex pattern which will accommodate for the following.

I get a response from a UDP server, it's a very long string and each word is separated by `\`, for example:

```
\g79g97\g879o\wot87gord\player_0\name0\g6868o\g78og89\g79g79\player_1\name1\gyuvui\yivyil\player_2\name2\g7g87\g67og9o\v78v9i7
```

I need the strings after `\player_n\`, so in the above example I would need `name0`, `name1` and `name3`,

I know this is the second regex question of the day but I have the book (Mastering Regular Expressions) on order! Thank you.

UPDATE. elusive's regex pattern will suffice, and I can add the match(0) to a textbox. However, what if I want to add all the matches to the text box ?

```
textBox1.Text += match.Captures[0].ToString(); //this works fine.
```

How do I add "all" match.captures to the text box? :s sorry for being so lame, this Regex class is brand new to me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that this test sample can help you

```
string inp = @"\g79g97\g879o\wot87gord\player_0\name0\g6868o\g78og89\g79g79\player_1\name1\gyuvui\yivyil\player_2\name2\g7g87\g67og9o\v78v9i7";
string rex = @"[\w]*[\\]player_[0-9]+[\\](?<name>[A-Za-z0-9]*)\b";
Regex re = new Regex(rex);
Match mat = re.Match(inp);
 for (Match m = re.Match(inp); m.Success; m = m.NextMatch())
{
     Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["name"]);
}
```

you can take the name of the player from the `m.Groups["name"]`

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
\\player_\d+\\([^\\]+)
```

Comment: +1 -- Hint: for regular expressions, it's best to post the pure expression without language specific additions. Like in this case, the regex literal notation `/slashes/` are not meaningful in C#.

Comment: Thanks for your addition! I used them in Perl for my entire life, so delimiters seem quite natural to me.

Comment: it didnt work, but if i remove the "/" from each end, i get a match "\player_n\playername\" .. which is ok, but i would prefer just "playername" by itself

Comment: You need to use the first match group. I do not know how this works in C#, but this is not too difficult in any other language that knows about regular expressions.

Comment: @brux: See http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html to get a quick overview (how to handle groups is explained there as well).

Comment: var match = Regex.Match(stringData, @"\\player_\d+\\([^\\]+)");
textBox1.Text += match.Captures[0].ToString();textBox1.Text += match.Captures[1].ToString();   it crashes when adding the second match to the textbox. if i remove this instruction then the first match (0) gets added fine.

Comment: its as though its oly finding 1 match, but there are plenty of player names in the string :s

Answer (score 1):

To get only the player name, you could use:

```
(?<=\\player_\d+\\)[^\\]+
```

This `(?<=\\player_\d+\\)` is something called a positive look-behind. It makes sure that the actual match `[^\\]+` is preceded by the expression in the parentheses.

In this case, it's even specific to only a few regex engines (.NET being among them, luckily), in that it contains a variable length expression (due to `\d+`). Most regex engines only support fixed-length look-behind.

In any case, look-behind is not necessarily the best approach to this problem, match groups are simpler easier to read.

Comment: hi tomolak, im going with the regex posted by elusive since it works ok. but if i try and add the second match to the textbox i get an "out of range error". if i remove that line the first match (0) is added ok. in the string i compare to the pattern, there are about 8 playernames :s

Comment: @brux: If you get "out of range" errors you are doing it wrong anyway. Always do range checks in your code.